# Bitwise: Why 14 & -14 is equals to 2 and 16 & -16 is equals to 16?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

it is a dummy question, but I need to understand it more deeply

Comment: 14 is `1110`.  -14 is `11110010`.  The bitwise and is `00000010`, or 2.  This is just a side effect of two's-complement arithmetic.  Negative numbers are not simply the bit-wise inverse of their positives.

Comment: @TimRoberts how can I archive the same result ? 
for example, by bin function in python I had the following result:


>>> bin(-14)
'-0b1110'
>>> bin(14)
'0b1110'
>>>

Comment: The output of `bin` for negative numbers is not compatible for bitwise operations. For negative arguments, it outputs the binary representation of the absolute value, prefixed with a `-`.

Comment: Right.  Things might be clearer if you were working in a language like C.  Python tries to be helpful, and that sometimes obscures what's going on behind the curtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python integers use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to store signed values. That means that positive numbers are stored simply as their bit sequence (so 14 is `00001110` since it's equal to 8 + 4 + 2). On the other hand, negative numbers are stored by taking their positive quantity, inverting it, and adding one. So -14 is `11110010`. We took the bitwise representation of 14 (`00001110`), inverted it (`11110001`), and added one (`11110010`).

But there's an added wrinkle. Python integer values are bignums; they can be arbitrarily large. So our usual notion of "this number is stored in N bits" breaks down. Instead, we may end up with two numbers of *differing* lengths. If we end up in that situation, we may have to *sign extend* the shorter one. This is just a fancy way of saying "take the most significant bit and repeat it until the number is long enough for our liking".

So in the case of `14` and `-14`, we have

```
0010
1110
```

We `&` them together. Only the second bit (counting from the right, or least significant bit) is true in both, so we get `0010`, or 2. On the other hand, with `16` and `-16`, we get

```
010000
110000
```

For `-16`, we took positive sixteen (`010000`), flipped all of the bits (`101111`), and then added one, which got carried *all* the way over to the second most significant bit (`110000`). When we `&` these, we get 16.

```
010000
```

See also [BitwiseOperators - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Comment: `All of the bits are significant in this operation`- and `"take the most significant bit and repeat it until the number is long enough for our liking".` Hmm, which is it, all signigicant, or as you clearly show in this answer you knew exactly what I meant by the word and were just being pedantic? I'm not going to vote an answer down just because I take issue with it. IM not that petty. Stack is rather toxic today I feel. What happened to the commuity of friendly engineers. My apologies to you for being equally toxic

Answer (score -1):

A bitwise operation is a binary operation.

In some representations of integers, one bit is used to represent the sign of the number. Depending upon which bit that is, will change the result of the bitwise &. In 2's complement, negative numbers are represented by inverting all the bits and then adding 1. There are many ways of representing real numbers in binary. Regardless, generally, a bitwise operation of a positive and negative number will always result in undefined behaviour. Probably why most calculators will only allow positive integers in bitwise operations. That is, calculators that are advanced enough to have such a feature.

EDIT: The specific numbers you chose are significant. The number 14 is represented in binary using less bits than 16. It just so happens that -16 and 16 are both exactly the same binary (looking only at the first five bits, since the rest are not significant when you come to & them together)

Now a bitwise & only sets a bit if that bit is set in both the numbers you are and-ing together.

`1110` = 14

`0010` = -14

`&0010` = 2!

`10000` = 16

`10000` = -16

`&10000` = 16!

There's your answer.

Comment: It's not correct to say that it's undefined behavior. Python defines integers as two's complement, so it's perfectly well-defined *in Python*. And I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "the rest are not significant when you & them together". All of the bits are significant in this operation, and -16 and 16 are certainly *not* the same when represented in two's complement (if they were, Python wouldn't be able to distinguish them)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I meant, generally speaking, it results in undefined behaviour - depending on what system is being used, how they are represented, etc. Of course specifics will define it. Apologies for not being clear. As to the high-order bits not being relevant, because you're doing a bitwise AND, where zero's will always give a zero. So in 16, after the fifth bit 1, the rest of the high-order bits are insignificant. Because the bitwise & will be zero for them all. The fact that they are all 1 for the negative is neither here nor there for this specific operation. They are zero in the answer.

Comment: Significant figures is a specific mathematical phrase, and it is in that context I used the word significant, if that helps any?